# Ist eine Stiftung Eigentümer oder Eigentümerin?

Tags: gender, proper-noun

Ich bin gerade über einen  [Text](https://netzpolitik.org/2016/mozilla-foundation-startet-initiative-fuer-urheberrechtsreform-make-create-innovate/) gestolpert, in dem ein übereifriger Blogger die weibliche Form für die *Mozilla Foundation* verwendet:

> Die gemeinnützige Stifterin ist Eigentümerin der Firefox-Entwicklerfirma    Mozilla Corporation [...] ¹

Die Form *Stifterin* ist hier eindeutig falsch, aber ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob eine *Stiftung* auch *Eigentümerin* sein kann, oder ob hier ebenfalls die neutrale Form *Eigentümer* hingehört.

Allgemeiner formuliert stellt sich mir also die Frage, ob der feminine Genus sich auch auf nachfolgende Wörter übertragen kann.

---

<sup>¹ Der Autor hat den Originaltext inzwischen korrigiert. Die *Stiftung* ist jetzt *Eigentümerin*. Meine obige Frage besteht also weiterhin.</sup>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Die Verwendung des Wortes "Eigentümerin" für juristische
Personen mit femininem Genus ist in juristischen Texten nicht unüblich. Google findet
2350 Links für *"Stiftung als Eigentümerin"* verglichen mit
2340 für *"Stiftung als Eigentümer"*,
9840 Links für *"AG als Eigentümerin"*
("AG" = "Aktiengesellschaft") verglichen mit
9780 für *"AG als Eigentümer"*,
7010 Links für *"die Gemeinde
als Eigentümerin"* verglichen mit
8500 für *"die Gemeinde als Eigentümer"*.

Das gilt analog auch für andere juristische Rollen, etwa "Klägerin" statt "Kläger" und
"Beklagte" statt "Beklagter".

Answer (score 4):

Das *Sprachlabor* der *Süddeutschen Zeitung* hat sich am 15. Oktober 2016 mit diesem Thema befasst; im Internet ist die Kolumne mit [*die Mühen der Ebene*](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/kolumne/sprachlabor-die-muehen-der-ebene-1.3205302) betitelt.

> Bleiben wir bei *Vorreiter/in*. Wenn die Duden-Grammatik von 1959 im Wesentlichen noch gilt, verhält es sich so, dass bei Personen das männliche oder weibliche Pendant zu verwenden ist: *Liesel ist die Hüterin der Gänse, Hans ist der Feind alles Bösen.* Die schöne Literatur hat auch hierin ihre Freiheiten: *Du warst die Königin, sie der Verbrecher* (Schiller, Maria Stuart). Bei Sachbegriffen können die weiblichen Formen gewählt werden, müssen es aber nicht: *Die Vernunft ist der Urheber/die Urheberin dieses Gesetzes.* Ist das Gleichsetzungsglied mit dem Prädikat fest verbunden, werden die Regeln der Kongruenz außer Kraft gesetzt. Sie sei, sagt Frau Marthe in Goethes „Faust“, *von je der Ordnung Freund gewesen.* Für die Kongruenz der Apposition gilt Ähnliches: *Was Venus band, die Bringerin des Glücks* (Schiller, „Die Piccolomini“).

Es ist also durchaus möglich und nicht falsch, eine Gesellschaft als *Stifterin* und als *Eigentümerin* zu bezeichnen. Frei nach dem Schlussabsatz des Sprachlabors lässt sich sagen:

»Die Mozilla Foundation kann also *Eigentümer* und *Eigentümerin* sein. Aus manchen Blickwinkeln mag das dubios sein, grammatikalisch nicht.«<sup>[1]</sup>

---

[1]: Leider geht der Originaltext unter Anderem über die Schweizerische Volkspartei als *Vorreiterin,* wodurch sich der letzte Satz wunderschön mit »politisch mag das dubios sein« formulieren lässt. Für die Mozilla-Foundation ist mir leider nichts wirklich vergleichbares eingefallen.

Answer (score 3):

Das Suffix -in ist dafür da, biologisches weibliches Geschlecht anzuzeigen.

Allerdings spricht nicht unbedingt etwas dagegen, es für den Zweck der grammatischen Kongruenz zu verwenden. Man muss sich bei dieser Entscheidung jedoch vor Augen führen, dass Leser über diese Form stolpern werden – weil diese Art der Kongruenz in der Allgemeinsprache völlig unerhört ist.

Was ich so auch schon oft gelesen habe:

> Die SPÖ (= Sozialdemokratische *Partei* Österreichs) ist die Rivalin der ÖVP.

Es klingt befremdlich.

Answer (score 1):

Man kann ohne weiteres schreiben:

> Der Eigentümer ist eine ältere Frau.
>
> Die Eigentümerin ist eine Gräfin.
>
> Der Tankwart ist ein junges Mädchen.

Rolle und Person müssen nicht unbedingt kongruent sein.

Was m.A. nach nicht geht:

> Die Friseuse war ein älterer Herr.

Wenn man sich entscheidet, die geschlechtsneutrale männliche Form der Rolle *nicht* zu verwenden, muss die Person auch dazu passen.