# Grammatikalisches Geschlecht

Tags: gender

Welche der folgenden Sätze sind nicht korrekt und warum, also welche Regel wird verwendet?

1.

> Die Bank ist Dienstleister für alle SparerInnen.

2. 

> Die Bank ist Dienstleisterin für alle SparerInnen

3. 

> Das Mädchen spielt mit den Ritterfiguren. Es möchte später selbst Ritter werden.

4. 

> Das Mädchen spielt mit den Ritterfiguren. Es möchte später selbst Ritterin werden.

Comment: Bitte schau dir mal die Diskussion an, die es zu normativen Fragen gibt: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/normative-fragen Es ist immer nicht so einfach, normative Fragen ohne Kontext zu beantworten. Vielleicht kannst du deine Frage genauer daraufhin eingrenzen, welche Autoritäten du als normatives Argument akzeptieren willst.

Comment: Geht es hier nur um Grammatik oder auch um Semantik? 3. ist m.E. grammatikalisch korrekt, semantisch aber ein Grenzfall. (Und ich hoffe, ich benutze das Wort "Semantik" in diesem Kontext richtig...)

Comment: Für die Dienstleisterin siehe https://german.stackexchange.com/q/31614/35111.

Comment: @DavidVogt, sehr interessanter Artikel. Lässt sich das Ergebnis so zusammenfassen: ist es ein juristischer Text, dann kommt wenn möglich das -in dran, ist es ein umgangssprachlicher Text dann geht beides und soll es ein grammatikalisch korrekter Text werden nach sprachwissenschaftlichen Maßstäben dann sollte das generische Maskulinum verwendet werden, weil alle anderen Formen der Umgangssprache entlehnt sind.

Comment: @ixolius Du hast den Nagel auf den Kopf getroffen - Die Frage hat leider (entgegen der Überschrift) genau nichts mit Grammatik zu tun - Sondern mit Semantik.

Comment: An alle: Bitte lest https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1340/wie-k%c3%b6nnen-wir-den-themenbereich-um-geschlechtergerechte-sprache-objektiv-halten, bevor ihr eine Antwort schreibt oder euch in Diskussionen in Kommentaren engagiert.

Comment: Sorry, aber diese Frage klingt sehr nach einer Hausübung. Dazu ist Stackexchange nicht da. Bei dieser Frage ist völlig unklar, was du selbst schon unternommen hast, um die Frage zu klären, und wie weit du mit du mit diesem Versuch gekommen bist. Was sind deine Ideen dazu?

Answer (score 4):

Alle deine Satzvorschlage könnten in geschriebenem Deutsch verwendet werden.

In allen praktischen Gespraechen wird man 1) und 3) verwerden. Satz 4) ist auch moeglich und Satz 2) ist richtig, klingt aber sehr förmlich und fast schon wie eine Ueberkorrektur.

Die Formen auf `-in` werden eher bei Personen verwendet (aber nicht zwingend) und bei abstrakten Entitaeten (etwa Unternehmen oder Behoerden) eher nicht (sind aber auch nicht ungrammatisch).

Comment: Welche Regel findet hier Anwendung?

Comment: Kannst du bitte für die entprechenden Beispiele aus der Frage das Originalzitat einfügen? 1), 3) und 4) finde ich sehr anstrengend.

Answer (score 1):

Korrektheit in der Sprache basiert in erster Linie auf Verständlichkeit - Was verständlich ist, kann nicht sehr falsch sein.

Aus diesem Blickwinkel sind alle deine Beispiele "richtig", und keines deiner Beispiele verstößt gegen irgendeine Grammatikregel (was deine explizite Frage war).

Ob man (1) oder (3) als "richtig" akzeptiert, hängt in erster Linie davon ab, ob man das *[generische Maskulinum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generisches_Maskulinum)*, das in diesen Sätzen verwendet wird, im Deutschen akzeptiert oder nicht. Die Diskussion darüber ist erst in zweiter Linie eine Frage der Grammatik, sondern eher eine Frage der gesellschaftlich/sozialen Akzeptanz. Zumindestens zur Zeit darf man davon ausgehen, das das generische Maskulinum eine Tatsache in der deutschen Sprache ist, von daher sind (1) und (3) derzeit akzeptiert und sowohl grammatikalisch (das sowieso) als auch semantisch richtig (die Frage, ob die Beispiele aus gesellschaftlich/sozialer Hinsicht richtig oder sinnvoll sind, wäre hier off-topic). Deine Beispiele, die das generische Maskulinum vermeiden (2) und (4), würden von vielen Sprechern als ungewöhnlich angesehen und den Eindruck erwecken, dass hinter der Nicht-Verwendung des an sich üblichen generischen Maskulinums eine Botschaft steckt (z.B. ein Anprangern).

*[Grammatische Kongruenz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kongruenz_(Grammatik))* ist eine Grundregel der deutschen Sprache. Sie ist in allen deinen Beispielen gegeben. *Semantische Kongruenz* (und das ist, wonach du fragst) ist in keiner Grammatik vorgegeben. So ist z.B. der Satz

> Der Arzt ist eine Ärztin

ein aus grammatischer Sicht vollkommen richtiger Satz (den man z.B. verwenden würde, wenn sich aufgrund der Verwendung des generischen Maskulinums ein Mißverständnis ergeben hätte, das man aufklären will), auch wenn die semantische Kongruenz eben nicht gegeben ist.

Comment: Ich verstehe noch nicht genau die Trennung zwischen semantischer und grammatikalische Kongruenz. Ich kann es nicht mehr prüfen, bin aber im festen Glauben die Formulierungen "die Zange ist Werkzeugin" oder "die Katze ist eine Kätzin" hätten vor wenigen Jahren in Aufsätzen zu Punktabzug geführt. Somit bin ich noch stark im Glauben das es dafür Regeln orthographischer Natur gibt, zumindest gab.

Comment: Bei "die Katze ist eine Kätzin" würde ich mich gegen einen Punktabzug wehren - Da eine Katze durchaus einen Sexus hat, den man klarstellen will. Bei "Die Zange ist Werkzeugin" würde ich es gar nicht erst versuchen, da eben dies nicht der Fall ist  - das ist einfach nur Unsinn. Orthografie hat übrigens *überhaupt nix* damit zu tun.

Comment: sorry dachte Orthographie steht als Begriff für Rechtschreibung, Grammatik und Ausdruck. Zwecks Zange, dabei erkenne ich den Unterschied zur Bank nicht, die hat auch keinen sexus.

Comment: Bei der Bank funktioniert es meinem Verständnis nach nur, weil sie als (juristische) Person angesehen wird. Nur deshalb kann sie auch eine "Dienstleisterin" sein. Eine Küchenmaschine wird man nicht als Dienstleisterin bezeichnen, auch wenn sie sehr viel Arbeit übernimmt.

Comment: @HalvarF, genau das habe ich dem von DavidVogt (verlinkten Artikel)[german.stackexchange.com/q/31614/35111] auch entnommen. Da diese Terminologie aber nicht Teil der "Standardsprache" ist. Vermute ich auch ganz stark das dies nicht die gängige Lehrmeinung ist zumindest war.

Comment: Ich sehe es so, dass in solchen Bereichen, in denen die Mehrheit der Sprachgemeinschaft keine klaren Regeln erkennen kann, sich sehr verschiedene Gebräuche etablieren, die dann auch nicht mehr in ein festes Muster zu pressen sind. "Kätzin" hat andere Gründe zu existieren als "Dienstleisterin", bei "Die Wand ist die Trägerin der Decke" hat vielleicht jemand gerade mal nicht sehr tief über verschiedene Geschlechterbegriffe nachgedacht, bei "Das Mädchen will Ritterin werden" spielen vielleicht politische Ansichten über weibliche Sichtbarkeit eine Rolle.

Comment: @HalvarF Drum schrieb ich ja oben "Botschaft"

Comment: @tofro, ja, sehe ich auch so. Sorry ich hätte es dazuschreiben sollen, das war eine Antwort auf den Kommentar davor.

Comment: @HalvarF, es geht doch um eine kleine Anzahl von Wissenschaftlern, die die Entwicklung von Sprache erforschen, Muster erkennen und diese in Definitionen gießen, dass Wissenschaft überhaupt möglich macht. Und allem Anschein nach hat sich in der Diskussion herausgestellt, daß der Gebrauch von Dienstleisterin uä der Terminologie der Juristen entspringt. Und das zeigt ganz klar eine Motivation in Form einer Regel für welche Substantive diese akzeptiert wird.

Comment: @Hölderlin `-in` wird in der Regel nur bei Berufsbezeichnungen oder Nominalisierungen auf `-er` verwendet. Eine Ausnahme ist `Hündin`, aber Worte wie `Werkzeugin` oder `Kätzin` werden allenfalls als Scherz verstanden.

Comment: Wir wählen nächste Woche eine neue Bürgerinnenmeisterin.

Answer (score 0):

Zunächst ist es wichtig, zwischen *grammatikalischem* und *biologischem* Geschlecht zu unterscheiden. Ersteres kommt *der Bank* zu, zweiteres nicht.

"Die Bank" mag zwar ein Femininum sein, *weiblich* ist sie deshalb aber nicht. Aus diesem Grund "öffnet sie" zwar ihre Türen, "ihre Adresse" ist auch da-und-dort, aber sie ist keine Dienstleister*in* - sondern Dienstleister.

Der Grund liegt im Umstand, daß das Deutsche sogenannte *generische* Ausdrücke besitzt, die homonym mit dem männlichen Geschlecht sind.*) "Arzt" bezeichnet jemanden mit medizinischer Ausbildung unbestimmten Geschlechts, "Ärztin" hingegen ausdrücklich eine Frau. Die Endsilbe "-in" wird aber für *biologisch* weibliche *Personen* verwendet. Eben, um das Geschlecht von Personen, das beim Generikum unbestimmt bleibt, anzugeben. *Die Bank* ist weder weiblich noch eine Person.

Ebenso ist "Dienstleister" (wenn schon nicht jemand, dann) etwas, das Dienste leistet - wenn nämlich "die Bank" eine Dienstleister*in* ist, dann ist "das Kreditinstitut" - was? Dienstleistum? Dienstleistendes?

---

*) Man spricht deshalb vom *generischen Maskulinum*, was eigentlich falsch ist, weil das *Generikum* zwar homonym mit dem *Maskulinum* ist, aber deshalb nicht dasselbe. Im Satz

> Ich lege den Kiefer auf die Kiefer.

ist einmal von einem Körperteil und einmal von einem Baum die Rede. Das sind zwei unterschiedliche Wörter, die durch die gleiche Lautfolge ausgedrückt werden. Trotzdem sind es verschiedene Wörter - oder ich habe einen Ast im Mund.

Wer will, kann jetzt darüber klagen, daß es kein *generisches Femininum* gibt oder auch darüber, daß sich das Maskulinum mit dem Generikum eine Form teilen muß, während das Femininum eine eigene Form bekommen hat. Müssen sich Frauen beim Ausdruck "der Arzt" mitgemeint fühlen? Gegenfrage: müssen sich Männer bei "die Person" mitgemeint fühlen?

Comment: Mit gegenteiliger Meinung: https://www.dwds.de/wb/-in#d-1-2

Comment: @DavidVogt, welche Rolle spielt die von dir verlinkte Seite unter Sprachwissenschaftlern? Ich lese das erste Mal vom Begriff Kätzin (= weibliche Katze). So habe ich das noch niemanden sagen gehört.

Comment: @bakunin, deine Erklärung leuchtet mir insofern ein, dass ich glaube das wäre die Lehrmeinung gewesen, Betonung liegt auf gewesen. Kann man in diesem Kontext von normativen Regeln sprechen oder ist das deine persönliche Meinung?

Comment: @Hölderlin: Es gibt in der Sprache - generell - keine "normativen Regeln". Jeder kann alles auf die Art sagen, die ihm genehm ist, ohne gegen Gesetze oder dgl. zu verstoßen. Manches ist dann vielleicht *unverständlich*, aber  *unerlaubt* ist es nicht. Wie ich schon wiederholt angemerkt habe, sind grammatikalische Regeln *post festum*. Sie beschreiben im Nachhinein, was vorher gesprochen/geschrieben wurde.

Comment: @bakunin `...normative Regeln... ` So ganz verstehe ich deinen Ansatz hier nicht man wird doch in der Schule ständig danach bewertet. Und auch im juristischen Sinne hat man nicht jede Freiheit zu sagen was man will.

Comment: @Hölderlin: in der Schule wird eine "Standardsprache" gelehrt - das bedeutet aber nicht, daß "die Sprache" so ist, sondern nur, daß das, was in der Schule gelehrt wird, eine bestimmte Form hat. In der Schule wird auch das Rechnen mit arabischen Ziffern gelehrt, aber mit zB römischen Zahlzeichen zu rechnen ist nicht "verboten". "Normative Regeln" sind Gesetze, Vorschriften, ... Alles das gibt es in der Sprache nicht. Daß zB "ohne" ein Akkusativobjekt verlangt hat niemand "festgelegt", so, wie man 50km/h in der Stadt festgelegt hat - es ist in der Entwicklung der Sprache einfach üblich geworden.

Comment: @Hölderlin: und "ohne verlangt Akkusativ" wurde erst eine "Regel", als es jeder so gemacht hat. Die "Regel" beschreibt aber nur, was eben üblich ist (und schon vorher war), zum Unterschied von der Höchstgeschwindigkeit in der Stadt, die vor der Einführung auch überschritten werden konnte, danach aber Gesetz war, an das sich alle halten müssen.

Comment: @Hölderlin: "Ich habe 2 Katzen, nämlich einen Kater und eine Kätzin." Wie sonst soll ich denn sonst hervorheben, dass eine meiner beiden Katzen weiblich ist? Bei Hunden macht man das ja ganz gleich: "Ich habe einen Rüden und eine Hündin". Guck mal Ratgebervideos über die Haltung von Katzen oder lies Zeitschriften, die sich auf Katzenhaltung spezialisiert haben. Da begegnet dir immer wieder das Wort Kätzin.

Comment: @Alina, im Der Große Duden von 1980 ist der Begriff Kätzin auch zu finden. Allerdings ist das offtopic,,weil es im Kern der Diskussion um die Substantive ohne sexus geht.

Answer (score -3):

Das Mädchen - will sie ein männlicher oder weiblicher Ritter werden? (Beides ist gleichermaßen unwahrscheinlich).

“Dienstleister” ist ein unabhängiges Wort zu Bank und braucht nicht weiblich zu sein. Andererseits “Die Bank öffnet ihre Türen”.

Comment: Es heißt ja nicht der Tür sondern die Tür. Der Vergleich hinkt also.

Comment: Es heisst `Ihre Tueren` weil das grammatische Geschlecht von `Bank` nun einmal weiblich ist. Man sagt ja nicht `seine Tueren` in diesem Kontext.

Comment: Ja so lässt sich auch Ihre Dienstleister oder Ihre Dienstleisterinnen sagen. Der Vergleich hinkt in meinen Augen immer noch.